# Inline images appear shifted down relative to text

Tags: org-mode, images

To speed up visually scanning my org file I would like to add icons to my headings. I am using 16x16 images which seem to fit well with the size of the font, but the images always appear slightly offset, lower than they should be.

Is this expected behavior? Is there a way to fix it so it is vertically aligned with the text? Thanks.

[image: example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the image with an`:ascent` property of value `center`.

Advising `org-display-inline-images` might be a way of doing this in `org-mode`, though it will apply to all images.

```
(defadvice org-display-inline-images (around center-images activate)
  (let ((create-image-orig (symbol-function 'create-image)))
    (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'create-image)
               (lambda (file-or-data &optional type data-p &rest props)
                 (apply create-image-orig file-or-data type data-p
                        (plist-put props :ascent 'center)))))
      ad-do-it)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @politza. I can see a doc of the Image Descriptor in section 37.17.2 of the emacs manual, but the org syntax is simply (in my example above)  [[file:/usr/share/emacs/24.4/etc/images/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/emacs.png]] so I'm not sure where I would put the :ascent.

Comment: If it is not possible with org-mode syntax, perhaps another question would be, how can I make an image appear as in the example by using just elisp code?

Comment: Thank you so much @politza for graciously writing that code. I look forward to the day I know elisp well enough to do that. Your solution works perfectly and was just what I was looking for. I do find that it helps me searching for headlines and I hope it helps others.